# Input Validation on Parsed Code

Tags: java, validation, parsing, input

In the below code the user is prompted to enter a numerical grade or to hit "s" || "S" to skip this requirement. The input is in the form of a string. In case the input is not "s"||"S", the input is parsed as a double. The code works perfectly. Now, I want to do input data validation and restrict the input to either "s" or "S" or any Number from 0-100. Is there a way to do it without creating each term in the form of a string? e.g. ( line == "0" || line == "1" etc... till 100

```
// Prompting the user for Score (Numerical Grade)
System.out.println("Kindly input Numerical Score:    (Enter s to Skip)"); 

// reading the input into the line variable of string datatype
String line = input.nextLine(); 

// checking if line =="s" or =="S" to skip, otherwise
// the value is parsed into a double

if("s".equals(line) || "S".equals(line))
{
}else try
{
        score = Double.parseDouble(line);
        System.out.println(score);
} catch( NumberFormatException nfe)
{

}
```

Comment: you appear to be asking questions which are tiny increments over the previous. Why don't you actually have a go at it yourself, rather than asking to be spoon fed?

Comment: The best way to do it is to try and write some more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already parsing the value to get a `Double`. Just check the value of the variable.

```
if (score >= 0 && score <= 100) {
    doXYZ();
 } else {
     notProcessing();
 }
```